# Exporting data from sql with php to excel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, excel, mysqli

I am trying to export sql to csv with php and this is what I managed to do. It works well without 2 things: 
1. Before the sql data that is outputted in the csv I get the HTML code of the current page for some reason.
2. How can I change the table header rows? Want to rename the table header column in the csv.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM user_history WHERE member_id = '$user_id'");
$num_fields = $result->field_count;
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Number";
for($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++ ) {
    $Obj = $result->fetch_field_direct($i);
    $headers[] = $Obj->name."\t";
}
$current_date = date("y/m/d");
$filename = "MyFileName" . $current_date . ".csv";
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
    header('Content-Type: text/csv');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    echo "Title of Your CSV File\n\n";
    // Write mysql headers to csv
    fputcsv($fp, $headers);
    $row_tally = 0;
    // Write mysql rows to csv
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    $row_tally = $row_tally + 1;
    echo $row_tally.",";
        fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
    }
    die;
}
```

Comment: So what happens if you do `$header .= $result->fetch_field_direct($i)."\t";` as shown in that question? While changing all `\\n` to `\n` and `"\\t"` to `"\t"` and `"\\r"` to `"\r"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Same thing.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch_field_direct` returns an object with no __toString() method.  According to [this](http://www.phpf1.com/manual/mysqli-fetch-field-direct.html) you need to change the code:

```
$header .= $result->fetch_field_direct($i)."\\t";
```

To:

```
$Obj = $result->fetch_field_direct($i);
$header .= $Obj->name."\t";
```

Secondly if you print "\\t" then you will literally get \t.  `print "\t";` will give you the tab character.

Comment: Changed accordingly, but now I am getting `Notice: Undefined variable: header`

Comment: Managed to fix that by declaring header and data before the while, and a download box with reports.xls appear, but the contents are not ok, it prints out the contents of the current page and the data from the query but in a non-readable style. It;s like a coding screen-shoot.

Comment: Make sure you concatenate "\t" and "\n" and not "\\t" and "\\n".

Comment: Hey, I updated, tried with another script but encountered the problems updated 1 and 2.